# German Macintosh keyboard missing on Ubuntu 22.04 German

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mac, language-support, german

I'm trying to select the german Macintosh keyboard layout on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, the system language is set to german too but there is no keyboard layout available.

There are many other languages available as Macintosh layout but unfortunately no german one. I've used the search to look for german and macintosh layouts but a layout with both is missing. How can I add it?

I'm doing the following, when looking for the layout.

1. open the system settings
2. go to keyboard
3. click on the plus to add a new keyboard
4. click on the button with the three dots to get more options
5. scroll down to the more button and click on it
6. enter in the search field macintosh
7. unfortunately no German keyboard with Macintosh layout even though there are many other languages available like portugese, french, italian, russian, japanese...

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've added a step by step description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you don't find the German layout under *Other* is that the German locale has been generated on your system. Following your step-by-step description, you ought to see a "German" option after step 3 or possibly after step 4. If you click that option, a sub menu with several German keyboard layouts ought to be shown, including *German (Macintosh)*

Comment: Thanks, I found it now, had to click on the German layout and then I had more different german keyboards available.